# Ошибка при попытке задать размеры элементов Activity через Java-класс

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Итак, у меня есть куча элементов в одной `Activity`. Возьмём парочку:

```
LinearLayout mainLinearContainer;
ScrollView stopWatchScroll;
```

Попытка проинициализировать и задать размеры:

```
mainLinearContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear_container);
stopWatchScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.stop_watch_scroll);

mainLinearContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, resolutionY + (int) (101 * scale)));
stopWatchScroll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, resolutionY + (int) (101 * scale)));
```

По логике, если я задаю размеры `LinearLayout`, то мне и пользоваться нужно `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, но в таком случае, вылетает ошибка:

```
05-17 14:00:57.386 23774-23774/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch, PID: 23774
                                                                                       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:431)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Насколько я понимаю, выбрасывает `ClassCastException` и сообщает, что не может привести к `FrameLayout`. Но если я меняю на `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, исключение исчезает и всё работает, но размеры нулевые:

```
    Log.d("mainLinearContainer", String.format("%d, %d", mainLinearContainer.getWidth(), mainLinearContainer.getHeight()));

05-17 14:05:04.621 24008-24008/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/mainLinearContainer: 0, 0
```

Подскажите, в чём проблема. Желательно развёрнуто и с решением.

UPD. Выложил весь класс.

```
package ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.fragments.Timer;
import ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.fragments.Timer2;

public class StopWatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Static sizes of display.
     */
    public static int resolutionX;
    public static int resolutionY;
    public static float dpHeight;
    public static float dpWidth;

    /**
     * All layouts in this activity.
     */
    LinearLayout mainLinearContainer;
    ScrollView stopWatchScroll;
    LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalMenu;
    LinearLayout horizontalMenuLayout;
    LinearLayout timerMainFrame;
    ConstraintLayout upArrowLayout;
    ConstraintLayout mainFragmentLayout;
    ScrollView fragmentBelowMain;
    LinearLayout contentBelowMain;

    /**
     * All fragments on this activity & its utils.
     */
    Timer timer;
    Timer2 timer2;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stop_watch_scroll_layout);

        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        getResolutions();
        defineDensity();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer2 = new Timer2();

        mainLinearContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear_container);
        stopWatchScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.stop_watch_scroll);
        mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear_layout);
        horizontalMenu = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
        horizontalMenuLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu_layout);
        timerMainFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.timer_main_frame);
        upArrowLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.up_arrow_layout);
        mainFragmentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_fragment_layout);
        fragmentBelowMain = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_below_main_view);
        contentBelowMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_below_main);

        mainLinearContainer.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, resolutionY + (int) (101 * scale)));
        stopWatchScroll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, resolutionY + (int) (101 * scale)));
        mainLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, resolutionY + (int) (101 * scale)));
        horizontalMenu.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, (int) (101 * scale)));
        timerMainFrame.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, (int) (resolutionY * 0.6)));
        fragmentBelowMain.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(resolutionX, (int) (resolutionY * 0.4)));

        Log.d("mainLinearContainer", String.format("%d, %d", mainLinearContainer.getWidth(), mainLinearContainer.getHeight()));
        Log.d("stopWatchScroll", String.format("%d, %d", stopWatchScroll.getWidth(), stopWatchScroll.getHeight()));
        Log.d("mainLinearLayout", String.format("%d, %d", mainLinearLayout.getWidth(), mainLinearLayout.getHeight()));
        Log.d("horizontalMenu", String.format("%d, %d", horizontalMenu.getWidth(), horizontalMenu.getHeight()));
        Log.d("timerMainFrame", String.format("%d, %d", timerMainFrame.getWidth(), timerMainFrame.getHeight()));
        Log.d("fragmentBelowMain", String.format("%d, %d", fragmentBelowMain.getWidth(), fragmentBelowMain.getHeight()));

        Log.d("calcDP", String.valueOf(calcDP(100)));

        stopWatchScroll.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                stopWatchScroll.scrollBy(0, (int) calcDP(101));
            }
        });
    }

    private void getResolutions() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);

        resolutionX = metrics.widthPixels;
        resolutionY = metrics.heightPixels;

        Log.d("resX", String.valueOf(resolutionX));
        Log.d("resY", String.valueOf(resolutionY));
    }

    public float calcDP(int i) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, i, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public void defineDensity() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        Log.d("density", String.valueOf(displayMetrics.density));
        Log.d("heightPixels", String.valueOf(displayMetrics.heightPixels));
        Log.d("widthPixels", String.valueOf(displayMetrics.widthPixels));
        Log.d("dpHeight", String.valueOf(dpHeight));
        Log.d("dpWidth", String.valueOf(dpWidth));
    }

    public void onClickMenu(View view) {
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Log.d("onClick", String.valueOf(fragmentTransaction));

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.timer1:
                Log.d("onClick", "timer");
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_view, timer);
                break;
            case R.id.timer2:
                Log.d("onClick", "timer2");
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_view, timer2);
                break;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("1");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        Log.d("onClick", "commited");
    }
}
```

UPD2. Значения переменных на примере `mainLinearContainer`. Итак, возвращаемые значения:

```
05-17 15:26:50.180 7548-7548/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/resolutionX: 720
05-17 15:26:50.180 7548-7548/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/resolutionY: 1184
05-17 15:26:50.180 7548-7548/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/density: 2.0
```

Это ширина и высота в пикселях, а также, коэффициент размера в dp к размеру в пикселях.

Узнаём размер layout:

```
Log.d("mainLinearContainer1", String.valueOf(mainLinearContainer.getLayoutParams().height));

05-17 15:32:12.110 11787-11787/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/mainLinearContainer1: -1
```

Размер `null` (-1).

Присваиваем лэйауту нужное значение, как учил `@ЮрийСПб`:

```
mainLinearContainer.getLayoutParams().height = resolutionY + (int) (101 * scale);
```

Результат вполне ожидаемый:

```
05-17 15:38:02.445 15048-15048/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/mainLinearContainer: 1386
```

Но когда берём через гетер, то по нулям:

```
Log.d("mainLinearContainer", String.format("%d, %d", mainLinearContainer.getWidth(), mainLinearContainer.getHeight()));

05-17 15:38:02.445 15048-15048/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/mainLinearContainer: 0, 0
```

И, по всей видимости, именно нули используются, поскольку экран эмулятора должен ездить как ScrollView, а он не ездит, значит, все значения всех переменных по нулям, как будто я вообще ничего не делал в Java-классе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LayoutParams` всегда для к-л вьюхи являются параметрами с типом родительского контейнера.Т.е.  для LinearLayout внутри FrameLayout они будут  `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`

Размеры же вьюх получать сложно и надо делать это по разному в зависимости от ситуации, того, что вы хотите получать и в какой момент. Для начала попробуйте ваш способ получения в onResume   использовать. Или получать их из `LayoutParams` как-то так:

```
 int height = view.getLayoutParams().height;
```

Comment: Так проблема-то не получить, а задать. Я и так вижу, что они имеют нулевые значения (это видно по экрану на AVD).

Comment: Я весь класс выложил, чтобы понятнее было.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов, ну... Если у вас назначаемые значения не 0 на момент назначения, то попробуйте так назначать: `view.getLayoutParams().height = resolutionY;` и `view.getLayoutParams().width = resolutionX;`

Comment: Значения присваиваются, но на практике — ноль. Добавил в вопрос описание процесса.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов, `getHeight()`, вроде, возвращает или пиксели или константы. При этом пиксели - только после отрисовки экрана. А это примерно когда `onResume()` вызовется. Если у вас `-1` возвращается, значит это, вроде, `match_parent`. Т.е. у вас, видимо, переназначаются параметры.